# dnf: additionaly install optional packages to already installed group?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

I installed Group "XYZ" without optional packages.

How do I install the group with optional packages, without removing and reinstalling it?

Answer (score 2):

What about if you mark the group as removed and reinstall it with `--with-optional` switch?

```
dnf group mark remove
dnf group install --with-optional group-name
```

Answer (score 1):

`dnf` is intelligent enough to allow you to install optional packages even after you've performed a `groupinstall` previously. Simply re-run the `groupinstall` command with the `--with-optional` switch.

#### Example

Here I've installed the group `graphics`:

```
[root@tambourie slm]# dnf groupinstall graphics
Last metadata expiration check: 0:16:49 ago on Sun 09 Jul 2023 11:14:17 PM EDT.
Dependencies resolved.
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                            Architecture                                      Version                                               Repository                                          Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing Groups:
 Graphics

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================

Is this ok [y/N]: y
Complete!
```

We can see that this package has optional packages like so:

```
[root@tambourie slm]# dnf group info graphics
Last metadata expiration check: 0:17:09 ago on Sun 09 Jul 2023 11:14:17 PM EDT.
Group: Graphics
 Description: This group includes packages to help you manipulate and scan images.
 Optional Packages:
   ImageMagick
   Panini
   asciio
   asymptote
...
...
```

If we re-run with the `--with-optional` switch:

```
[root@tambourie slm]# dnf groupinstall Graphics --with-optional
Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:17 ago on Sun 09 Jul 2023 11:14:17 PM EDT.
Dependencies resolved.
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                           Architecture                         Version                                                          Repository                             Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing group/module packages:
 Panini                                                            x86_64                               0.73.0-13.fc38                                                   fedora                                227 k
 asciio                                                            noarch                               1.51.3-23.fc38                                                   fedora                                 10 k
 asymptote                                                         x86_64                               2.85-1.fc38                                                      fedora                                5.0 M
 cbrpager                                                          x86_64                               0.9.22-26.fc38                                                   fedora                                 54 k
 dcraw                                                             x86_64                               9.28.0-18.fc38                                                   fedora                                278 k
...
...
```

`dnf` can figure it out and install the optional packages.